# How do I .apply or .replace multiple columns at once in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The code below works..

`df['Forecast'] = df['Forecast'].apply(lambda x: '0' if x == '' else x)`

`df['Yield'] = df['Yield'].apply(lambda x: '0' if x == '' else x)`

but when I try to do together, it doesn't work

`to_change = ['Forecast', 'Yield']`

`df[to_change] = df[to_change].apply(lambda x: '0' if x == '' else x)`

it gives the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How to perform these functions (replace or apply) together at once without writing a new code line for every column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) ?

```
to_change     = ['Forecast', 'Yield']
df[to_change] = df[to_change].replace(to_replace='', value='0')
#            or df[to_change].replace({'': '0'})
```

*tested*.

---

An illustration. Say you have `df` defined as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '_else_'  : ['', '', ''],
    'Forecast': ['', 'y', 'o'],
    'Yield'   : ['k', '', 'm'],
})
```

i.e.

```
>>> df
  _else_ Forecast Yield
0                     k
1               y      
2               o     m
```

It turns out that doing

```
>>> df[to_change] = df[to_change].replace({'': '0'})
```

has changed `df` as follows

```
>>> df
  _else_ Forecast Yield
0               0     k
1               y     0
2               o     m
```

Comment: Thanks 
`df[to_change].replace({'': '0'})` only works if I `replace({'': '0'} , regex=True)`

Comment: 1.0.4 sorry my bad. it's my first week trying to code. It's working fine for this example.
I was trying to remove the commas from number in yield and forecast (which for some reason is in str format) so I used the code  `df[to_change] = df[to_change].replace({',': ''}, regex=True)` . now I'll astype(int) the columns.